# using Boost Log to generate application time distribution?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I have an Eigen-based C++ application where I'm interested in generating the time distributions for the different steps in a way one could generate a time distribution performance plot. This will help quickly finding the current bottlenecks e.g. compiling using MKL as backend etc.

How can I use Boost Log for this purpose? is there built in support in Boost Log to show the elapsed time from the last logging statement for a specific level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it, the Boost Log library (I'm using the latest 1.54) supports predefined and custom attributes and this is how the functionality is offered. The predefined attribute [Stop Watch (timer)](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/attributes.html#log.detailed.attributes.timer) *"provides high resolution of the time estimation and can even be used as a simple in-place performance profiling tool."*